# Dot in base url codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter-2

I have got a source code of a codeigniter project.in the config.php file there is a dot in the base url.

Code:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://codeigniter-ajaxcrud.local/';
```

what is the purpose of using this dot in the base url?

Comment: May be it is virtual host

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So actually they have created virtual host in local machine.

You also can create virtual host in your local machine, Please find below example so you can understand it in brief.

Open this file if you are using xampp, and add this line at the end of page.

> c:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf

```
<VirtualHost codeigniter-ajaxcrud.local:80>
      DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/codeigniter-ajaxcrud"
      ServerName codeigniter-ajaxcrud.local
      ServerAlias www.codeigniter-ajaxcrud.local
      <Directory "c:/xampp/htdocs/codeigniter-ajaxcrud">
          Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
          AllowOverride All
          Require all Granted
      </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Once you done with this add codeigniter-ajaxcrud.local in hosts file.
This file will be located in below location in windows.

> Drivers/etc/host

add below line at end of the page.

```
127.0.0.1         codeigniter-ajaxcrud.local
```

Once you done with this please save all files and restart apache server.
Than this host will work.

Comment: Thanks..what would be the url look like in the browser .should i type like this? .http://localhost/codeigniter-ajax-crud/

Comment: I typed http://codeigniter-ajaxcrud.local/ in the url bar of the browser but showing error 404 object not found :(

Comment: Please check this steps. 1. You have to follow above mentioned rules. 2. Restart Xampp server. 3. Change `base_url` in `config.php` file

Comment: do i need to change the host name in the database.php file?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, It is virtual host. you can try to create virtual host with same name using:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts

or change the URL of your path.

Purpose:
When you develop web app then the URL taken like: 
http://localhost/codeigniter/

here `codeigniter` is your main folder where you develop website..

and then you create any controller (`e.g Users`) then URL looks like http://localhost/codeigniter/users

then web app take the `codeigniter` as controller and `users` as method.
but actually the `codeigniter` is your root directory of your project not a controller.

So you have to create virtual host to deprecate this issue.